# run a process to /dev/null in python

Tags: python, linux

How do I run the following in Python?

```
/some/path/and/exec arg > /dev/null
```

I got this:

```
call(["/some/path/and/exec","arg"])
```

How do I insert the output of the `exec` process to `/dev/null` and keep the print output of my python process as usual? As in, don't redirect everything to stdout?

Comment: You probably meant `> /dev/null` in your `sh` equivalent, not `< /dev/null`, which would redirect `stdin`, not `stdout`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Python 3.3 and later, just use [`subprocess.DEVNULL`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL):

```
call(["/some/path/and/exec","arg"], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
```

Note that this redirects both `stdout` and `stderr`. If you only wanted to redirect `stdout` (as your `sh` line implies you might), leave out the `stderr=DEVNULL` part.

If you need to be compatible with older versions, you can use [`os.devnull`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.devnull). So, this works for everything from 2.6 on (including 3.3):

```
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
    call(["/some/path/and/exec","arg"], stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
```

Or, for 2.4 and later (still including 3.3):

```
devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
try:
    call(["/some/path/and/exec","arg"], stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
finally:
    devnull.close()
```

Before 2.4, there was no `subprocess` module, so that's as far back as you can reasonably go.

Comment: Great thanks...but if I use the 2.7 solution will it still work with 3.x?

Comment: @user1432779: Yes. I'll put full compatibility details in.

Comment: Thanks..but I think I have a problem..I'm trying to write a script on the server that would start another server..however when I run it through the shell on the process I get after a few seconds :Exception AttributeError: "'Popen' object has no attribute '_child_created'" in <bound method Popen.__del__ of <subprocess.Popen object at 0xed9790>> ignored
{ans:0}

Comment: @user1432779: I don't understand what you're saying. What do you mean "when I run it through the shell on the process"? If you have a new problem that's too hard to explain in a comment, create a new question, or edit your existing one.

Comment: the shell of the server sorry

Comment: I've posted a new one...it seems that this solution creates a new problem :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182780/error-when-running-call-in-python-subprocess