# error when running call() in Python subprocess

Tags: python, linux, dev-null

i'm trying to run:

```
 try:
    with open(subprocess.PIPE, 'w') as pipe:
          call(["/usr/sbin/atms","-k"], stdout=pipe, stderr=pipe)                                        
          call(["/usr/sbin/atms","/usr/sbin/atms.conf"],stdout=pipe,stder=pipe)
 except Exception, e:
          print e
```

I now get

```
 coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

What does it mean?

Thanks

Comment: There is no need to use `os.devnull` to redirect stdout or err. Just use `subprocess.PIPE` and ignore the output.

Comment: Ok..will try it..does it mean to replace the line in the code to subprocess.PIPE instead of os.devnull?

Comment: Exactly; no need to redirect to the `/dev/null` if you can just pipe and ignore. I am not stating that that will solve your issue, just that using `/dev/null` is a shell solution, and this is Python.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried it and added the result above.. :-(

Comment: You do *not* need to open `PIPE` as a file. Use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, see the documentation. :-)

Comment: changed it to call(["/usr/sbin/atms","-k"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
and now I got the same error from the beginning "'Popen' object has no attribute '_child_created'" in <bound method Popen.__del__ of <subprocess.Popen object at 0xd81790>> ignored
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stder'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open()` is used for files, and expects a filename not a pipe.

Instead of `.call()`, you could use `Popen`:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', 'print "test"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.stdout.read()
'test\r\n'
```